# JSX Unexpected Token after Return Array

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, jsx, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm creating my own Gutenberg block in WordPress for the first time. I am receiving an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

The token in question appears after my return array

**index.js**

```
edit({attributes, setAttributes}) {
  const{
    title,
    backgroundColor,
  } = attributes;

  return ([
    <InspectorControls>
      /** Code Block **/
    </InspectorControls>,

    <div>
      /** Code Block **/
    </div>
  ]);

},

/** Rest of Code **/
```

The '<' of the  tag is what is being flagged and I'm unsure why as I've followed tutorials that show this should be the same code set up.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by returning multiple elements in your return statement without a root/parent element. Its a frustrating error to encounter as syntax wise, everything seems fine, its more a concept that isn't immediately clear from the docs/tutorials when you start creating first WordPress gutenberg block with React.

To resolve this issue, all child elements need to belong to a parent/root element, commonly seen as `<div className={className}> .. </div>` in [WordPress Gutenberg](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-edit-save/#classname) examples, where all elements including InspectorControls are returned, eg:

```
return ([
<div className={className}> // Add this 
    <InspectorControls>
     /** Code Block **/
    </InspectorControls>

    <div>
    /** Code Block **/
    </div>
</div> // Add enclosing tag
  ]);
```

Alternatively, this can resolve by wrapping the child elements in `<> ... </>` ([shorthand for a ReactJS fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)):

```
return ([
<> // Add this (generic ReactJS fragment) 
    <InspectorControls>
     /** Code Block **/
    </InspectorControls>

    <div>
    /** Code Block **/
    </div>
</> // Add enclosing tag
  ]);
```

I found the [Rendering Elements of the ReactJS docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) helpful for better understanding how to write for WordPress Gutenberg.